# Is it possible to remove the max value of a number

Tags: math, limits

I have a mathematical formula which generates prime numbers.  The numbers grow exponentially, and in 7 iterations the value hits `inf` and then `nan`.

Is there a way to remove those limits or is there a language that doesn't have limits?

Comment: Computers are limited, so there will always be limits in programming languages, there's nothing you can do against it.

Comment: You can increase those limits with some effort (e.g. bignum), but to remove them you need a Turing machine.

Comment: Thanks, this will help me alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many languages such as Python 3 can handle arbitrarily large integers (limited only by RAM), so you can certainly play around with integers having thousands of digits. For example, it took less than a second to compute `10,000! = 284625968091705451890641321211...` (with 35,660 digits hidden in the ...). In most languages, floating point numbers tend to be limited to what you can represent with 64 bits, though there are various libraries for arbitrary-precision floating point numbers. In no case can you exceed all limits.

If you are using C or C++ the [GNU MP Bignum Library](https://gmplib.org/) allows you to do arbitrary precision integer and floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks, so Python is one of the best compilers on solving arithmetic problems. I will remake my code in python and see how it goes.

Comment: Is python 3 the only version that have this propety, I just used python 3.5 on atom, running the program at the prompt command and it went the same as my c++ version of the program

Comment: Python 3.5 works like Python 3 as far as that goes. Are you doing floating point arithmetic or integer arithmetic? `inf` is a float value but prime numbers are ints. Perhaps you could post your code.

Comment: You are using floating point operations and numbers. Also -- it seems to be an infinite loop since `z` is always 1 and nothing in the body of the loop changes the value of `z`. Also -- this seems to have nothing to do with generating primes but is maybe related to Fermat's factoring algorithm.

Comment: yes, I moddified the value of the numbers but not the structure (it is a public server so i didnt post the formula a public server)

Comment: the infinite loop was on purpose, and the last line of the code was made to stop the formula